# Can I create an app with only the public key if I don't go with Google Play store

Tags: java, android, keystore, app-signing

Is it possible to create an app and use the public key of its previous version and Install the app without going through Google Play Store?

I, mean, there is an app in Google Play Store, and I have its source code in a notepad only.

So, if I update the code and fit it in Android Studio and build the app, then how will it be possible to update the app in the users machines who already using it.

Trying to update the code stating an error saying, the certificate does not match.

Is it possible to update it simply by copying the Cert.rsa file from the previous version apk/zip and distribute the users hand to hand, without going through Google Play Store.

Comment: You don't need to re-key unless your private key has been compromised, and you can use the same certificate if it hasn't expired. Please don't conflate certificates with public keys.

Comment: I don't have any keys, but the app was signed with a certificate. I have the source code in a text file only.

Comment: Then you can't sign it, and whatever consequences flow from that will flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot install an update without the private signing key, that I know. You can update the code and install it as a separate app, though. This means you will need to change the `appId` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: So, if I distribute the app without Google Play store, still I will need the private key to update the app? I was thinking of copying the cert.rsa file into the apk/zip.

Comment: @James Yes, you will still need to sign the app with the correct key in order for the device to allow the update. This is enforced by the Android OS, not Google Play.